# Do the Apple Earphones with Remote and Mic work with an iPhone 3G?

Tags: iphone, remote-control, compatibility, microphone, ear-phones

On the [Apple product site](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB770G/B?fnode=MTY1NDA1MA) it says the Apple Earphones with Remote and Mic aren't compatible with an iPhone 3G. I would assume, though, that the headphones and the mic will work, but the remote control buttons might not. However, the [more basic version](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MA814LL/A?fnode=MTY1NDA1MA) works with a 3G; these feature just one button to answer or end a call. So the main button of the more advanced earphones might work as well?

Has anybody ever used the combination of an iPhone 3G and the Apple Earphones with Remote and Mic and can report on their compatibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked; the "play/pause" button works, but not the "up/down volume" buttons.